# What are the differences between Drizzle and the Truffle React box?

Tags: truffle, react, drizzle, truffle-box

Truffle has many "boxes", two of which are:

```sh
truffle unbox react
```

And:

```sh
truffle unbox drizzle
```

They both seem to be focused on frontend development. Other than Drizzle being based on a Redux store, what are the differences between the two?